# SQL select statement in HSQLDB with where clause

Tags: select, where-clause, hsqldb, spring-jdbc

I experiment unexepected results with HSQLDB 2.3.3.
My table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE job_schedule (  
job_id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
job_name VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
job_group VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
job_start BIGINT NOT NULL,
job_data VARCHAR(255) NULL,
job_body CLOB NULL)

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_job_schedule_name ON job_schedule
(job_name, job_group)
```

I use HSQL Database Manager to select all rows from the table:

```
SELECT * FROM job_schedule

JOB_ID JOB_NAME                             JOB_GROUP                            JOB_START     JOB_DATA                                                                                                     JOB_BODY 
------ ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------ ------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ -------- 
79     cb9b5abe-f6b6-4670-a702-5bec4f6b9217 edab5d78-3533-11e5-a151-feff819cdc9f 1442848923391 {"duration":69,"start":0,"channel":"ba981e18-e2d8-42ce-a7af-147ff40f075f","content":"360449L0E0ZqbNnH.mp4"}           
80     a0e49194-c01c-4c77-ac4c-95f60bd3528b edab5d78-3533-11e5-a151-feff819cdc9f 1442848866000 {"duration":57,"start":0,"channel":"ba981e18-e2d8-42ce-a7af-147ff40f075f","content":"294913LWi2e1RuY9e.mp4"}
```

My Java program uses the following class (that extends a Spring Framework 4.2.0 class):

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class DefaultJobManager extends JdbcDaoSupport {
     private DefaultJobManager.QueryIdSql myQueryIdSql;

     @Override
     protected void initTemplateConfig() {
         JdbcTemplate db = getJdbcTemplate();
         myQueryIdSql = new DefaultJobManager.QueryIdSql(db);
     }

     @Transactional(readOnly = true)
     public List<Long> listJobs(long startMin, long startMax) {
         return myQueryIdSql.execute(startMin, startMax);
     }

     private static final class QueryIdSql extends MappingSqlQuery<Long> {
         QueryIdSql(JdbcTemplate db) {
         setJdbcTemplate(db);
         setSql("select job_id from job_schedule " +
                "where job_start between ? and ?");
         setResultSetType(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY);
         setUpdatableResults(false);
         declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Types.BIGINT));    
         declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Types.BIGINT));
         compile();
     }

     protected Long mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        return rs.getLong(1);
     }
 }
```

The method `listJobs(1442848866000L, 1442848923391L)` returns a `List` with only one item.

The HSQLDB generates the `db.sql.log` file and in this file I can read:

```
select job_id from job_schedule where job_start between ? and ? (1442848866000,1442848923391)
```

Comment: Sorry, I have tried to isolate my problem in HSQLDB, but I have made a silly mistake. I've just complete the post with the Java program where my problem had started.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in my use of Spring JDBC and not in HSQLDB.
In `DefaultJobManager` class (that extends `JdbcDaoSupport`), I use more than one class that extends `RdbmsOperation` and in some of them I set the `maxRows` property to `1`, but this property is propagated to the corresponding property of the `JdbcTemplate` object, and I share the `JdbcTemplate` instance owned by the `DefaultJobManager` object with **all** of the `RdbmsOperation` objects.
Other properties propagated from `RdbmsOperation` to `JdbcTemplate` are `fetchSize` and `queryTimeout`.
If you wanna make some tuning on a `RdbmsOperation` object, you should let it use its default `JdbcTemplate` instance. You can share the `DataSource` object among `RdbmsOperation` objects but not the `JdbcTemplate` object.